# Change the div with image when refreshed the page, but responsive, with a specific image on the phone and another on the desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, responsive-design, responsive

Change the image when refreshed the page, but responsive, with a specific image on the phone and another on the desktop, and I want these images to change every time I update the page in no specific order.

```
<div id="random-img">
   <div class ="random-desktop">
       <img src="">
   </div>
   <div class ="random-mobile">
      <img src="">
   </div>
</div>
```

Something like that

```
function changeImage(imgOrder)   {
            var myImg = ["img/1.png", "img/2.png", "img/3.png", 
           "img/1mini.png", "img/2mini.png", "img/3mini.png" ]; 
            var imageShown = document.body.style.backgroundImage;
            var newImageNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length);
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+myImages[newImageNumber]+')';}
        window.onload=changeImage;
```

Or Like That

```
var image = new Array ();
image[0] = "";
image[1] = "";
image[2] = "";
image[3] = "";
image[4] = "";
image[5] = "";
image[6] = "";

var size = image.length
var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())

$('#random-img img').attr('src',image[x]);
```

Comment: Did you tried css Media queries ? https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries Do you really need js to do it ? or it can be okay with css ?

Comment: Hello, I need the images to be random, and I need to do only with JS

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to get the screen size and use two array.

```
function changeImage(imgOrder)   {
   var myImages = ["img/1.png", "img/2.png", "img/3.png"]; 
   var myMiniImg = ["img/1mini.png", "img/2mini.png", "img/3mini.png"];
   var mobileScreenWidth = 728;
   var imageShown = document.body.style.backgroundImage;
   var newImageNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length);
   if (window.innerWidth > mobileScreenWidth) {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+myImages[newImageNumber]+')';
   }
   else {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+myMiniImg[newImageNumber]+')';
   }
}
window.onload=changeImage;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, gave me this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: myImages is not defined "

How would it look for this situation:
`<div id = "random-img">
<div class = "random-desktop"> img </div>
<div class = "random-mobile"> img </div>
</div>`

Comment: Just edited my code...your code too has the same problem, you are using a variable myImages that is never declared...you probably renamed it to myImg

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it’s not what I’m looking for yet, I wanted change to be specific within this div#random-img

Answer (score 0):

Or just use CSS only?
Can you try with below CSS without JS?

```
#random-img img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4sLnzqh6/

Answer (score 0):

so I managed to solve it and leave it the way I want it, thanks a lot, here is the code:

```
    <div class="content custom-test-img  position-relative data-banner-1" style="display: none;">
    <picture>
        <source media="(max-width: 375px)" srcset="test.png">
        <source media="(max-width: 640px)" srcset="test.png">
        <source media="(max-width: 1024px)" srcset="test.png">
        <source media="(min-width: 1025px)" srcset="test.png">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </picture>
</div>


<div class="content custom-test-img  position-relative data-banner-2" style="display: none;">
    <picture>
        <source media="(max-width: 375px)" srcset="test.png">
        <source media="(max-width: 640px)" srcset="test.png">
        <source media="(max-width: 1024px)" srcset="test.png">
        <source media="(min-width: 1025px)" srcset="test.png">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </picture>
</div>


<div class="content custom-test-img  position-relative data-banner-3" style="display: none;">
    <picture>
        <source media="(max-width: 375px)" srcset="test.png">
        <source media="(max-width: 640px)" srcset="test.png">
        <source media="(max-width: 1024px)" srcset="test.png">
        <source media="(min-width: 1025px)" srcset="test.png">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </picture>
</div>

require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/cookies',
    'domReady!'
], function ($) {

    $('.custom-test-img').css('display','none')

        if (window.localStorage) {

            let dataBanner = localStorage.getItem('databanner');

            if(dataBanner == null) {
                localStorage.setItem('databanner', 1);
                $('.data-banner-1').css('display', 'block');
            } else {    

                    if (dataBanner == 3 ) {
                            localStorage.setItem('databanner', 1);
                            $('.data-banner-1').css('display', 'block');

                    } else {
                        localStorage.setItem('databanner', +dataBanner+1 );
                        dataBanner = localStorage.getItem('databanner');
                        $('.data-banner-' + dataBanner).css('display', 'block');
                    }
            }
            
        } else {
            console.log("Sorry, your browser do not support local storage.");

            if(dataBannerCookie == '2' || dataBannerCookie == null){
                $.cookie('databanner', '1', { expires: 7, path: '/' });

                console.log(dataBannerCookie + ' - 2 active');
            } else{
                $.cookie('databanner', '2', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
                console.log(dataBannerCookie + ' - 1 active');
            }

        }

});
```